# Reading multiple lines from a file using TCL?

Tags: tcl

How do I read more than a single line in a file using tcl? That is by default the gets command reads till a new line is found, how do I change this behaviour to read a file till a specific character is found?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind reading over a bit, you can do it by looping with `gets` or `read` in a loop:

```
set data ""
while {[gets $chan line] >= 0} {
    set idx [string first $whatToLookFor $line]
    if {$idx == -1} {
        append data $line\n
    } else {
        # Decrement idx; don't want first character of $whatToLookFor
        append data [string range $line 0 [incr idx -1]]
        break
    }
}
# Data has everything up to but not including $whatToLookFor
```

If you're looking for multiline patterns, I suggest reading the whole file into memory and working on that. It's just so much easier than trying to write a correct matcher:

```
set data [read $chan]
set idx [string first $whatToLookFor $data]
if {$idx > -1} {
    set data [string range $data 0 [incr idx -1]]
}
```

This latter form will also work just fine with binary data. Just remember to `fconfigure $chan -translation binary` first if you're doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `fconfigure`.

```
set fp [open "somefile" r]
fconfigure $fp -eofchar "char"
set data [read $fp]
close $fp
```

Comment: Can `-eofchar` be more than 1 character?

Comment: That, I don't think so. (Perhaps @DonalFellows will chime in with an alternative way.) At worst though, you'll have to read line by line and concatenate some strings; that shouldn't be too horrible.

Comment: The `eofchar` really does have to be a character since the check for whether it is being seen is done with equality on a “basic transfer unit”. Well, actually it might even need to be a byte; I'm not quite sure where it is processed in the channel stack relative to the encoding handling (the code is complex). To be honest, I wouldn't recommend using anything other than an empty string or `\u001a` for it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Donal's good advice, you could get a list of records by reading the whole file and splitting on the record separator:

```
package require textutil::split
set records [textutil::splitx [read $chan] "record_separator"]
```

[Documentation](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/textutil_split.html)